# React Native Nested Flat Lists Poor Performance

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a nested flat list so a user can scroll vertically and horizontally. The outer flat list is horizontal and the inner flat list is vertical. I noticed the Vertical console keeps being printed way too often. I was able to reproduce the issue in a much simpler example in [github](https://github.com/sp71/NestedFlatLists/tree/master). The performance is so bad for this simple example that the screen becomes just white if you scroll horizontally too many times. Feel free to clone the repo and run the app, only 1 file called App.js contains the real code so its very simple. I wonder why React Native is performing so bad?

[image: Demo]

App.js

```
const DATA = generate(40);

function generate(val) {
  return new Array(val).fill().map((e, i) => {
    return data(i + 1);
  });
}

function data(page) {
  switch (page) {
    case 1:
      return require('./data/1.json');
    // more cases go from 2 -> 40
    case 40:
      return require('./data/40.json');
  }
}

function App() {
  console.log('Horizontal')
  return (
      <FlatList
        data={DATA} // DATA is a nested array
        style={styles.appContainer}
        renderItem={subList}
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        windowSize={1}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
          return index.toString();
        }}
      />
  );
};

const subList = (props) => {
  console.log('Vertical')
  return (
    <FlatList
      data={props.item}
      style={styles.flatRow}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      initialNumToRender={20}
      windowSize={2}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => {
        return index.toString();
      }}
    />
  );
};

function Line(props) {
  const {email, first_name} = props.item.item;
  return (
    <View style={styles.line}>
      <Text style={styles.textFont}>{first_name}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.subtitleFont}>{email}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const renderItem = (props) => <Line item={props} />;
```

Comment: I think this article helps you a lot
https://codingislove.com/optimize-react-native-flatlist-performance/#:~:text=FlatList%20is%20the%20component%20in,optimize%20react%20native%20flatlist%20performance.

Comment: Yeah I read a few articles online similar but couldn't find a true solution. Not using in-line arrow functions for render, no images here, maxToRenderPerBatch didn't help :(, tried windowSize but didn't help, can't use getItemLayout as each cell will be dynamic height in real app, using keyextractor, think I tried memo but no luck on that either. Maybe react-native isn't ready for this usecase?

Comment: You didn't use useCallback for renderItem (subList)
You didn't use useCallback for keyExtractor

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @SoftDev. Didn't make much impact tho :(